# getting 'this' with named thenable

Tags: ember.js

I'm stumbling around with promises in Ember and have a problem where I can get code to work within an anonymous function but prefer the clarity a named function would provide but in doing so I loose my reference to `this`.

So, for example I have a Ember Data model called 'enumeration' and so I've created a helper class where I can specify the `enumName` property and when the promise is evaluated the `enumList` get populated with the results of the appropriate enumeration record:

```
module.exports = App.Enumeration = Ember.Object.extend({

    // reference to the ember-data store
    store: null,
    // this is the 'id' of in the enum model
    enumName: null,         
    // the enum is converted to a promise and either looked up using the Enum model or passed through as an array
    enumPromise: null,
    enumChanged: function() { 
        var _this = this;
        this.set('enumPromise', this.get('store').find('enum', enumeration)
            .then(function(success) {
                _this.set('enumList', success.get('data'));
            })
        );
    }.observes('enumName'), 

    enumList: []
});
```

This seems to work as expected, however I'd like to have the `then(success,fail)` call be sent to named functions:

```
module.exports = App.Enumeration = Ember.Object.extend({

    // reference to the ember-data store
    store: null,
    // this is the 'id' of in the enum model
    enumName: null,         
    // the enum is converted to a promise and either looked up using the Enum model or passed through as an array
    enumPromise: null,
    enumChanged: function() { 
        var enumeration = this.get('enumName');
        var _this = this;
        this.set('enumPromise', this.get('store').find('enum', enumeration)
            .then(this.successfulEnumRetrieval,this.failedEnumRetrieval);
        );
    }.observes('enumName'), 

    enumList: [],

    successfulEnumRetrieval: function(result) {
        this.set('enumList', result);
    },
    failedEnumRetrieval: function(error) {
        console.log('failed retrieving enumeration: ', error)
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having is how to gain access to the App.Enumeration's context (aka, "this"). In the named functions, somehow they fail complaining that `set()` isn't part of the object. I suspect this is a broader Javascript scoping problem but whether it's a "promise" problem or a "javascript scoping" problem I could use some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right when you said that this is a broader Javascript scoping problem. Well, not a problem as such. The right way to do this would be using [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Here is a nice [article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/23/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/) about it.

You can use it like this in your code.

```
this.set('enumPromise', this.get('store').find('enum', enumeration)
    .then(function(success) {
        this.set('enumList', success.get('data'));
    }.bind(this))
);
```